# Syntax error near END keyword?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am defining this SQL Server SP, but I am getting the following error message, which is not very detailed:

`Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'end'.   32  8`

I am closing all `BEGIN` with an `END`, therefore I can't get it why is the engine complaining.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.addReading
    @deviceId int,
    @facilityId int,
    @reading real,
    @insertionTimestamp datetime2,
    @isMeter bit
AS BEGIN
    IF (@isMeter = 1)
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @lastReading real;
            DECLARE @newReading real;

            -- Get last reading
            SELECT @lastReading = lastReading FROM devices
            WHERE facilityId = @facilityId AND id = @deviceId;

            -- Update lastReading with the new one
            UPDATE devices SET lastReading = @reading
            WHERE facilityId = @facilityId AND id = @deviceId;

            IF (@lastReading IS NOT NULL)
                BEGIN
                    SET @newReading = @reading - @lastReading;

                    INSERT INTO readings (deviceId, facilityId, reading, insertionTimestamp)
                    VALUES (@deviceId, @facilityId, @newReading, @insertionTimestamp);
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    -- Do nothing
                END
        END   -- ---------------------------------- LINE 32 (ERROR HERE!)
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO readings (deviceId, facilityId, reading, insertionTimestamp)
            VALUES (@deviceId, @facilityId, @reading, @insertionTimestamp);
        END
END

GO
```

What is wrong with the `END`?

Comment: you have a begin .. end without any code in it. Sql server does not likes that, remove it and the error will be gone

Comment: Remove the else part of the mention after @lastReading IS NOT NULL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [**MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190487.aspx)

```
BEGIN  
    { sql_statement | statement_block }   
END
```

*{ sql_statement | statement_block }*

> Is any valid Transact-SQL statement or statement grouping as defined
>   by using a statement block.

You need to have a valid Transact-SQL statement between `Begin` and `END`, so cannot have this

```
 ELSE
     BEGIN
     -- Do nothing
     END
```

If your `ELSE` part is not going to do anything then remove it

```
IF (@isMeter = 1)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @lastReading real;
        DECLARE @newReading real;

        -- Get last reading
        SELECT @lastReading = lastReading FROM devices
        WHERE facilityId = @facilityId AND id = @deviceId;

        -- Update lastReading with the new one
        UPDATE devices SET lastReading = @reading
        WHERE facilityId = @facilityId AND id = @deviceId;

        IF (@lastReading IS NOT NULL)
            BEGIN
                SET @newReading = @reading - @lastReading;

                INSERT INTO readings (deviceId, facilityId, reading, insertionTimestamp)
                VALUES (@deviceId, @facilityId, @newReading, @insertionTimestamp);
            END
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

If you declare `ELSE` statement it can't be empty. So if you have only `BEGIN` `END` it goes in error.

If you don't want to use `ELSE`, remove it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the else. You must put code between BEGIN and END. The commented Do nothing doesn't nothing. You could add a SELECT 0 if you want add something else later, else you should delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Begin and END statement need minimum one line of code

```
 BEGIN
      -- Do nothing
        PRINT 1
  END
```